# Adding the button implemented from "Printer, e-mail and PDF versions" in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I am using [Printer, e-mail and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print), and I was wondering if there were a way I could place the print button in node.tpl.php above the `$content` area, instead of through the Drupal administration area. Could that be done through a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the administration area, disable the insertion of the link, then add the following (depending on which modules you use) to your `node.tpl.php`:

- Print: `<?php l('Print', 'print/'.$node->nid); ?>`
- Print to PDF: `<?php l('PDF version', 'printpdf/'.$node->nid); ?>`
- Send by email: `<?php l('Send by email', 'printmail/'.$node->nid); ?>`

---

However given you have your own theme template, it could be better to just modify the CSS applied to the print link(s) to be in a different location on screen.

Comment: +1 for CSS being a good way to deal with this, leaving the markup nicely ordered.

Comment: Great -- thanks! So then use absolute Positioning to move it above the $content area? Yeah I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another options could be to use something like [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to manage the layout of your node display rather than writing custom templates. Since the Print module implements hook_content_extra_fields, the Print option should show up as a CCK field, that you could then drap/drop to your desired location.

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't even aware of this module. I have to try it out, but from what I've read it might just change my entire Drupal life, LOL.

Thanks!!!